# How to Stop a Thread at a given point?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was trying to stop some threads, read some things about the proper way to do it gracefully, but I must be doind something wrong because it simply doesn't work. At first I tried without the `lock()` with `_IsRunning` being volatile, then tried with the locks. Here is what I've got.

```
private volatile bool _IsRunning;
private static readonly object runLock = new object();

public void Start()
{
    if (_IsRunning == true)
        return;
    _IsRunning = true;
    (new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(SendLoop))).Start();
}

public void Stop()
{
    lock (runLock)
    {
        _IsRunning = false;
    }
}

private void SendLoop()
{
    while (_IsRunning)
    {
        lock (runLock)
        {
            if (_sockets.Count > 0)
            {
                //some stuff
            }
            else
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint at my `while()`, and `_IsRunnig` is still true even though I passed in `Stop()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lock is required here because of the way your start method is written, however, you only need the lock in `Start()` (where it isn't now) and `Stop()`, since they're the only ones that could potentially cause a race condition in your case.

I would remove the lock from your `SendLoop()` method entirely (it's causing a [DeadLock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) since `Stop` is waiting on the lock to set `_isRunning`, and your `SendLoop` is holding the lock until `_isRunning` is set to false).  Right now, when you call `Stop()`, the lock is preventing it from ever setting `_isRunning = false;`

However, you will need locks in your `Start()` and `Stop()` methods (unless you rework the way they are structured entirely). Something like:

```
public void Start()
{
    lock (runLock)
    {
        if (_IsRunning == true)
            return;
        _IsRunning = true;
        (new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(SendLoop))).Start();
    }
}

public void Stop()
{
    lock (runLock)
    {
        _IsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

This will protect you from starting 2 threads, and will also keep Stop from stopping before the thread has started.

Comment: Thanks! Your anwser made me aware of a real deadlock problem! In my solution, I do need to have a lock during the loop, but the Sleep must definately be kept out of it!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reorganize your loop a little bit.  Right now you are holding the lock on runLock for a very long period of time.  This will cause anyone calling the Stop method to hang until the if block succeeds or the Sleep call returns.  This can lead to issues because you cannot look at _isRunning when the Stop method is called, only when it returns.  Try reorganizing your code as follows

```
private void SendLoop() {
  do {
    if ( _sockets.Count > 0 ) {
    } else { 
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
    bool shouldContinue;
    lock ( runLock ) { 
      shouldContinue = _IsRunning;
    }
  while(shouldContinue);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure this is the issue.  But at least it should help clear things up a bit.