# C# WinForm not Responsive - System.Speech - Help

Tags: c#, speechsynthesizer

Here's a code from the C# Windows Form

```
SpeechSynthesizer audio = new SpeechSynthesizer(); 
audio.Speak(textBox1.Text);
```

- This will read anything that is in the textbox

**Problem in trying to implement the pause and stop feature.Any button or menuitem doesnt get clicked when the code reads something**

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Nothing gets executed here when the code is reading
    }
```

i just read there is SpeakProgressEventArgs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speakprogresseventargs%28VS.85%29.aspx

i tried synth...asyncancel... **but the click event of the button doesnt get executed**

Comment: Is the SpeechSynthesizer running in the UI thread?  You will probably have poor UI responsiveness if it's running in the same thread as the UI event loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the SpeakAsync() method instead.  That prevents the UI from blocking on the Speak() method, it cannot respond to button clicks while it is blocked.  You can use SpeakAsyncCancelAll() to stop it from nattering on.

Answer (score 3):

you need to manage this block `audio.Speak(textBox1.Text);` using [**Threads**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(VS.71).aspx)

```
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            SpeechSynthesizer audio = new SpeechSynthesizer(); 
            audio.Speak(textBox1.Text);
        });
        t.Start();
```

Now how to stop a running thread ? very well explained in this poster

- [**How to Stop a Thread at a given
  point.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/694804/how-to-stop-a-thread-at-a-given-point)